# Windows phone URL encoding issues(Windows phone)

Tags: c#, windows, url, uriencoding

A simple request to the server to get a file is giving some issues, Here's the url,

https://dc2-vault.myvzw.com/dv/api/user/c107a6db69104a10bc247a28fb81131e/search?query=contentType:audio/* AND (genre like 'RoyalJatt.Com )')&sort=name+asc&start=1&count=2147483647

then i do this,

```
url = Uri.EscapeUriString(url);
```

i get,

https://dc2-vault.myvzw.com/dv/api/user/c107a6db69104a10bc247a28fb81131e/search?query=contentType:audio/*%20AND%20(genre%20like%20'RoyalJatt.Com%20)')&sort=name+asc&start=1&count=2147483647

The problem here is this,

the query looks for a file with Genre RoyalJatt.Com%20) which should have been RoyalJatt.Com%20%29

For some reason, it is omitting the ")"

What can i do to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what i did and got it working.

> ```
>     private readonly static string reservedCharacters = "!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]";`
>
>     //Neither of Uri.EscapeUriString and Uri.EscapeDataString methods encodes 
>     //the RFC 2396 unreserved characters If you need these encoded then you 
>     //will have to manually encode them
>     public static string UrlEncode(string value)
>     {
>         if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
>             return String.Empty;
>
>         var sb = new StringBuilder();
>
>         foreach (char @char in value)
>         {
>             if (reservedCharacters.IndexOf(@char) == -1)
>                 sb.Append(@char);
>             else
>                 sb.AppendFormat("%{0:X2}", (int)@char);
>         }
>         return sb.ToString();
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it seems that encoding data for use in a url is not the same as encoding a url!

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace Model_Library
{
    [TestClass]
    public class test
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void test2()
        {
            string url = @"https://dc2-vault.myvzw.com/dv/api/user/c107a6db69104a10bc247a28fb81131e/";
            string data = @"search?query=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(@"contentType:audio/* AND (genre like 'RoyalJatt.Com )')") + @"&sort=name+asc&start=1&count=2147483647";
            string enc = Uri.EscapeUriString(url) + data;

            Console.Write(enc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if i change "RoyalJatt.Com )" to "RoyalJatt.Com" this does not create an issue.

Comment: sorry don't understand

Comment: Please don't reinvent the wheel... There are already existing classes like Uri, UriBuilder and  HttpUtility.ParseQueryString to deal with creation of urls and query string.s

Comment: I guess there's "whats the best way of building a url in c#?" and "Why doesn't Uri.EscapeUriString() encode my url as expected"

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov sorry to disagree... but Classes like HttpUtility does not exist in the Windows Phone applications or even windows applications. They are web based. I do admit that i have not added the necessary information that  i am working on a phone app. Anyways i have changed it now

Comment: My examole escapes the brackets doesnt it?